# How qml call static method from c++

Tags: c++11, qml, qt5.6

What I done:

validator.h:

```
class UTILSSHARED_EXPORT Validator: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Validator(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Validator();
    Q_INVOKABLE static bool validateMobile(const QString target);

};
```

main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Validator>("CT.Utils", 1, 0, "ValidatorKit", "It just a kit");
```

qml:

```
import CT.Utils 1.0
ValidatorKit.validateMobile("112344")
```

But unfortunately, I got an error that said: TypeError: Property 'validateMobile' of object [object Object] is not a function

So, how can I expose static method to qml correctly?

Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`qmlRegisterUncreatableType()` is about something else entirely.

What you actually need to do is expose a `Validator` instance as a context property to QML, or even better, [implement the validator as a singleton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType).

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Validator>("CT.Utils", 1, 0, "ValidatorKit", fooThatReturnsValidatorPtr);
```

Comment: There is no other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping.

Comment: Sadly, that works only for QObjects. Any solution for a Q_GADGET ?

Comment: I solved my issue by using a member in my application class. I had another idea of using a template class that would inherit bith my Q_GADGET and QObject, but did not go through.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to singleton type, it is possible to create a private singleton attached properties object which contains only static functions. It is more clear with an example:

```
class StaticValidator;

class Validator : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Validator(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Validator();
    
    // Put implementation in a source file to prevent compile errors.
    static StaticValidator* qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object) {
        Q_UNUSED(object);
        static StaticValidator instance;
        return &instance;
    }

    static bool validateMobile(const QString& target);
};

//Q_OBJECT does not work in inner classes.
class StaticValidator : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE inline bool validateMobile(const QString& target) const {
        return Validator::validateMobile(target);
    }

private:
    StaticValidator(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

friend class Validator;
};

QML_DECLARE_TYPE(Validator)
QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(Validator, QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)
```

Register type in main or somewhere:

```
qmlRegisterType<Validator>("Validator", 1, 0, "Validator");
```

Call function in QML:

```
import Validator 1.0
...
var result = Validator.validateMobile(target);
```

It should also work in Qt4, but I didn't test it.